# Link function in data explorer for posts

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

Wouldn't be nice if results in Data Explorer could link to the post they result in?

Please provide a `link` function that takes a `PostId` and returns a link to that post.

For example

```
-- Great Answers
-- Lists the answers a user owns that are eligible for the Great Answer Badge
SELECT P1.Score, P1.Id, P1.ParentId, P2.Title, link(P1.Id) as 'Link'
FROM Posts as P1  -- find responses of questions
JOIN Posts as P2 --And the question it responds to
ON P1.ParentId  = P2.Id
WHERE P1.PostTypeId = 2                 -- answers
AND P1.OwnerUserId = ##UserId##       -- by you
AND P1.Score > 100 --Which a score of over 100
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's already possible.

```
select p.Id as [Post Link] from Posts p
```

Comment: I spent 15 minutes and couldn't get it to work: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1407382/all-my-posts-on-the-se-network-with-markdown-and-html-content-plus-editors-and-s

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix The column has to be re-aliased to have the literal name `Post Link` (so it needs to be escaped as either `[Post Link]` or `"Post Link"`). But your query (on line 125) aliases it as `[Post ID]`; If you change it to `Posts.Id as [Post Link],` it will work.

Comment: @Dai Sorry that was an old comment I had forgot to come back and delete after everything was working. Another user (actually a Mod) modified the query and got everything working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

- SEDE (Stack Exchange Data Explorer) will only convert integer post Ids (e.g. `Posts.Id` and `PostHistory.PostId`) to clickable links if you alias (rename) the column to `Post Link`.

  - As "`Post Link`" contains a space you will need to escape it using either of these syntaxes:

    - `p.Id AS [Post Link]`
    - `p.Id AS "Post Link"`

For example:

```
SELECT
   p.Id AS [Post Link]
FROM
   Posts AS p
```

The `Id` values don't have to originate from `Posts.Id` at all and can come from anywhere, such as a CTE or an inner-`SELECT` query - they can also be completely unrelated, even random, numbers with no connection to `Posts` at all, for example here's a query that gets 10 random posts:

```
WITH randomNumbers AS (
    SELECT RAND( /*seed:*/ 123 ) AS n UNION ALL
    SELECT RAND() AS n UNION ALL
    SELECT RAND() AS n UNION ALL
    SELECT RAND() AS n UNION ALL
    SELECT RAND() AS n UNION ALL
    SELECT RAND() AS n UNION ALL
    SELECT RAND() AS n UNION ALL
    SELECT RAND() AS n UNION ALL
    SELECT RAND() AS n UNION ALL
    SELECT RAND() AS n
),
randomNumbersFrom1To40M AS (
    SELECT
        CONVERT( int, 1 + r.n * 40000000 ) AS RandomValue
    FROM
        randomNumbers AS r
)
SELECT
    r2.RandomValue AS "Post Link",  /* <-- Magic happens here. */
    r2.RandomValue
FROM
    randomNumbersFrom1MTo40M AS r2
```

Results:

[image]