# 'modified ... ago' does not always link to last activity

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, deleted-answers, last-activity

Normally, when the last activity on a question is a deleted answer, like in this case:

[image]

the link under (in this case) 'modified 2 days ago' contains a `lastactivity` parameter:
`https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54460/link-function-in-data-explorer-for-posts?lastactivity`, which upon clicking automatically scrolls to the deleted answer.

However, in this similar case:

[image]

the URL is `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374897/why-is-the-google-analytics-cookie-defined-as-strictly-necessary-and-saved-wit` *without* that parameter, so it ends up on the question itself, and you need to click on the 'Active today' widget below the title to get to the last activity. This *may* be caused by the long question title, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Seems whether the `?lastactivity` bit gets appended is tied to whether the question has answers, which is no when they are all deleted.

Comment: Not related, but if a user answered a questions and deleted the answer as the last activity on the question, would the *last modified* link still display the answerer's profile?